# Listing *.tif files in directories meeting certain criteria

Tags: r, string, directory, gsub, string-substitution

I want to list all *.tif files in directories that contain specific numeric values.
Example:
`Path_source <- "C:/Files/"`
Within this folder, I have 1000 folders, each named `jobXXX` where `XXX` stands for numeric value 1-999. So there is a folder `job0`, `job1`, ... , `job999`.
Within each `jobXXX` folder I have other folders and files. From this structure of folders I want to extract all files with the following pattern:

`Year <- 2021`

`file.ls <- list.files(path=Path_source, pattern=paste0("Text_",Year,".*\\.tif"),all.files = TRUE,  full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)`

So my missing element is now to filter the directories for folders with specific job numbers:

`jobs <- c(1,14,45,67,129,834)`

Example outcome:

`> file.ls`

`[1] "C:/Files/job14/folder12/Text_2021_anothertext_abc.tif"`

`[2] "C:/Files/job45/folder81/Text_2021_anothertext_efg.tif"`

Which function should I use?

Thank you

Comment: Please give 3 or 4 directories names examples (wanted and not wanted) and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

The following function creates part of the filenames. Then a `sapply` loop gets the directories in the vector returned by the function.

```
make_dir_name <- function(Path_prefix, job_prefix, job_number){
  fmt_string <- paste0(Path_prefix, job_prefix, "%d[^[:digit:]]+")
  sprintf(fmt_string, job_number)
}

jobs_dirs <- make_dir_name(Path_source, "job", jobs)
i <- sapply(jobs_dirs, \(d) grep(d, file.ls))
i <- unname(unlist(i))
file.ls[i]
```

---

### Test data

```
file.ls <-
c("C:/Files/job14/folder12/Text_2021_anothertext_abc.tif", 
  "C:/Files/job45/folder81/Text_2021_anothertext_efg.tif")
```

Comment: Thanks, this is not exactly what I need but very helpful! I prepared an example output to make my question clearer.

Comment: @MIH See if the edit solved it, I simplified the function.

Comment: It works great - much appreciated! Just the indexing file.ls[i] is interesting - it doesn't work.

Comment: @MIH What is the value of `i`?

Comment: I get a list and the directories are list names. 
`> i`
$`C:/Files/job45/folder81/Text_2021_anothertext_efg.tif`
`integer(0)`

Comment: @MIH Try `file.ls[unlist(i)]`.

Comment: > file.ls[unlist(i)]
character(0)

Comment: @MIH I have edited the answer again. With the test data in the question, it works with me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237929/discussion-between-rui-barradas-and-mih).

Answer (score 0):

Sticking with base r this might be of help.

```
files <- paste("job", seq(1,10), ".tif", sep = "")

numbers <- seq(1,10, by = 2)
files_I_Want <- paste("job",numbers, ".tif",sep = "")

files[files %in% files_I_Want]
```

Using the `%in%` operator I can see what files are in my constructed files I want vector.

Comment: Thanks, this is not exactly what I needed - I gave an example of output as I realised now I was not clear.